# How to get balance from a chain different than the one currently connected?

Tags: dapps, ethers.js, bridge

I am building a small bridge in order to learn about web3 and I would like to show the balance from the destination chain/network. For example, if I want to pass Ethereum from Ethereum mainnet to Avalanche, I would like to get the current balance in Avalanche.

Is there a way to achieve this? I have seen pages that do that. I use ethers so I am not sure if I would need to create 2 providers one for the source/currently selected network and the other one for the destination chain.

Thank you in advance and regards

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this resource about fetching balance on different chain than the one connected. It discusses using either two providers or an API to achieve the goal:

https://github.com/Uniswap/web3-react/discussions/466

Comment: Thank you very much! But how can I use two providers in the client server? I mean I am using currently Web3Provider from ethers to connect to the current selected chain. I see I can pass a network argument to Web3Provider constructor or I could use a JsonRPCProvider. However, in both cases I would need to specify the RPC Url which I could get from Alchemy, but I would then be exposing the RPC Url API key to the public which is bad if I am not mistaken. Do you see my point? Thank you again.